# Front end or back end ajax call for another url

Tags: ajax, ember.js, frontend, backend

I am making an Emberjs application which would parse podcast's rss feed.

In application you can add urls of rss feeds then the app would parse it and create a nice interface to listen to your favourite feeds.

My question is that where should i make the AJAX call, on the backend or on the frontend? Because right now i store the url-s on the backend and i send them down to the client side then i make ajax calls on the frontend and then parse the urls.

Which is better practice? Making calls on backend or on frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is best to make ajax call on the frontend for this case.
If you do it this way you reduce the path taken for the content to reach user which ensures good user experience. Unless it is your own backend(might not be the case if your confident about your code) that is providing the content it is best to do the call on frontend.

Your App ---->Your backend--->Actual feed---->Your Backend--->Your App

```
                            or
```

Your App-----> Actual Feed ----> You App

This reduces latency which is good.

Thank you I hope I answered correctly